# RegExp Delete rows contain NULL

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to delete all defective rows (at least one cell with a NULL value) in a string by using RegExp in Python..

Giving a string S = "header,header\nANNUL,ANNULLED\nnull,NILL\nNULL,NULL"

The table would look like below:

| header | header |
| --- | --- |
| ANNUL | ANNULLED |
| null | NILL |
| NULL | NULL |

Last row should be deleted.. Second row is not defective because null is lowercase..

the function I need to write should return below;

```
"header,header\nANNUL,ANNULLED\nnull,NILL"
```

I've wrote this:

```
S = "header,header\nANNUL,ANNULLED\nnull,NILL\nNULL,NULL"
rows = S.split('\n')
clean_list = []

for i in range(0,len(rows)):
    if re.search(r"^\s*NULL\s*",rows[i]) != None:
        print(rows)
    else:
        clean_list.append(rows[i])
        i+=1
```

And clean_list have below:

```
['header,header', 'ANNUL,ANNULLED', 'null,NILL']
```

My question is that how do I convert this clean list to a string by adding \n end of each row.. So it would look like below;

```
"header,header\nANNUL,ANNULLED\nnull,NILL"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't do, what you said you want to do.
Best, split your rows in cells:

```
table = "header,header\nANNUL,ANNULLED\nnull,NILL\nNULL,NULL"
rows = table.split('\n')

cleaned_rows = []
for row in rows:
    if "NULL" not in row.split(','):
        cleaned_rows.append(row)

cleanded_table = "\n".join(cleaned_rows)
```

or more compact with list comprehension:

```
table = "header,header\nANNUL,ANNULLED\nnull,NILL\nNULL,NULL"
cleanded_table = "\n".join(
    row if "NULL" not in row.split(',')
    for row in table.split("\n")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"\n".join(clean_list)`